# Purity related question

Tags: taharah, najis

If your penis touches your thigh does this  make the place that the penis touched impure? Or it still remains pure as it is just a body part

Comment: Pure i  believe (And Allah knows best)

Comment: What is the relevance between purity (taharah) and the touch of body parts? The believer is regarded as pure.

Answer (score 0):

The penis in of itself is pure, and so touching it with any part of the body does not cause impurity. The 3 madh'habs besides the Ĥanafī madh'hab consider touching the penis with the hand to be a nullifier of wudū, whereas touching with the hand does not nullify it in the Ĥanafī madh'hab.

However, all four madh'habs agree that the penis touching the thigh does not cause impurity nor does it nullify the wudū.